# VNCServer shows grey screen on port 1, but desktop environment works on other ports

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, vncserver, tightvnc

I am working on an Ubuntu 20.04 Server -and I am very new to this- and trying to use vncserver -which was installed by some other person-, while trying to make the server boot with VNCServer I changed crontab files, and after I was done the number 1 server was unreachable, it always automatically started with port 2. So I changed the crontab, and ran vncserver again but now there was an error concerning tmp/.X11-unix/X1 and it suggested for me to delete this file and I deleted the X1. I also deleted tmp/.X1-lock . However afterwards something weird happened, I started to get the default X11 grey screen on port 1. However on port 2 and port 3 I can get normal XFCE desktop environment. One may say that I can just use port 2 and 3, but if I can fix what happened with port 1, that would be awesome. I don't know if it help but: Also when the server starts on port 1, the local Ubuntu on server throws an error called "The notification area lost selection". Also after crontab changes the local background changed to xfce, instead of the default Ubuntu background.

My current xstartup file looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
xdrb $HOME/.Xresources
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
exec startxfce4
```

Comment: Could be that another service also runs that takes control of port 1. For example rdp uses vnc too, and it may be that port 1 is used there.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up but I think that's not the problem, I can VNC through Port 1 but all I have is grey screen and X cursor. If I VNC through other ports its fine. Still, I didn't know that the ports could be in use, so thank you for that again!

Comment: If something else uses that VNC port, another VNC instance would get a black or grey screen. In my case, I see that for a short time before it auto-disconnects me. But now that I think of it, it could also be a lock screen. Can you swipe up/down and get a login screen that way?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply: First of all: Thank you so much for your input! I think I have solved the issue by starting using XRDP, for some reason it fixed the port 1 not being usable error. Now everything works fine.